# Bijection+Closability?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was wondering whether a closable operator $A$ with domain $D(A)\subset H$ ($H$ is a Hilbert space) which is also bijective has an everywhere defined bounded inverse?

Thanks in advance.

Math.

Comment: We may also assume that $D(A)$ is dense.

Comment: If you have such an operator and remove one point from its domain, doesn't it still satisfy the conditions? Maybe you should ask about a "closed densely defined" operator".